# Simplifying an integral?

Tags: calculus

I was given the system $$y(t) = 0.5 \int_{-\infty}^\infty [x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)+x(\tau)\delta(t+\tau) ]d\tau$$ and I simplified it to $$y(t) = 0.5 [x(t) + \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t+\tau)d\tau  ]$$ my problem is that I have no idea what  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t+\tau)d\tau   $ can be simplified into. I am guessing either $x(-t)$ or $x(t)$ but I have no clue and my googling was not successful.

Comment: What are $x$ and $\delta$?  Just arbitrary functions?  Is $\delta$ the Kronecker delta?

Comment: $\delta$ is the dirac delta function and $x(t)$ is just an arbitrary input. @Jim

Comment: My book defines $x(t)*\delta(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau = x(t)$ and hence I can't seem to find how it is defined when it is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t+\tau)d\tau$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for a Dirac delta is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(0)$$
so just do the $u$-substitution $u = t + \tau$ so that your integral is in this form.

Comment: but wouldn't that give $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau = -x(t)$ if u substitution could be used? or since $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$ we can "ignore" the negative sign by setting $u = -(t-\tau)$ ?

Comment: By $u$-sub we get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t - \tau)\mathrm{d}\tau = -\int_\infty^{-\infty}x(t - u)\delta(u)\mathrm{d}u = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t - u)\delta(u)\mathrm{d}u = x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac delta is defined at $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x) dx = f(0)$. Then to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau) \delta(t+\tau) d\tau$, perform the substitution $u = t+\tau$. For this, $du = d\tau$, $\tau = u-t$, and the integral becomes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(u-t) \delta(u) du = x(0-t) = x(-t)$.